# How to fit different inputs into an sklearn Pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, pipeline

I am using Pipeline from sklearn to classify text.

In this example Pipeline I have a TfIDF vectorizer and some custom features wrapped with FeatureUnion and a classifier as the Pipeline steps, I then fit the training data and do the prediction:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion, Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

X = ['I am a sentence', 'an example']
Y = [1, 2]
X_dev = ['another sentence']

# load custom features and FeatureUnion with Vectorizer
features = []
measure_features = MeasureFeatures() # this class includes my custom features
features.append(('measure_features', measure_features))

countVecWord = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3), max_features= 4000)
features.append(('ngram', countVecWord))

all_features = FeatureUnion(features)

# classifier
LinearSVC1 = LinearSVC(tol=1e-4,  C = 0.10000000000000001)

pipeline = Pipeline(
    [('all', all_features ),
    ('clf', LinearSVC1),
    ])

pipeline.fit(X, Y)
y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_dev)

# etc.
```

The above code works just fine, but there is a twist. I want to do Part of Speech Tagging on the text and to use a different Vectorizer on the tagget text.

```
X = ['I am a sentence', 'an example']
X_tagged = do_tagging(X) 
# X_tagged = ['PP AUX DET NN', 'DET NN']
Y = [1, 2]
X_dev = ['another sentence']
X_dev_tagged = do_tagging(X_dev)

# load custom featues and FeatureUnion with Vectorizer
features = []
measure_features = MeasureFeatures() # this class includes my custom features
features.append(('measure_features', measure_features))

countVecWord = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3), max_features= 4000)
# new POS Vectorizer
countVecPOS = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 4), max_features= 2000)

features.append(('ngram', countVecWord))
features.append(('pos_ngram', countVecWord))

all_features = FeatureUnion(features)

# classifier
LinearSVC1 = LinearSVC(tol=1e-4,  C = 0.10000000000000001)

pipeline = Pipeline(
    [('all', all_features ),
    ('clf', LinearSVC1),
    ])

# how do I fit both X and X_tagged here
# how can the different vectorizers get either X or X_tagged?
pipeline.fit(X, Y)
y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_dev)

# etc.
```

How do I properly fit this kind of data? How can the two vectorizers differentiate between raw text and pos text? What are my options?

I also have custom features, some of them would take the raw text and others the POS text.

EDIT: Added MeasureFeatures()

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
import numpy as np

class MeasureFeatures(BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_feature_names(self):
        return np.array(['type_token', 'count_nouns'])

    def fit(self, documents, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, x_dataset):


        X_type_token = list()
        X_count_nouns = list()

        for sentence in x_dataset:

            # takes raw text and calculates type token ratio
            X_type_token.append(type_token_ratio(sentence))

            # takes pos tag text and counts number of noun pos tags (NN, NNS etc.)
            X_count_nouns.append(count_nouns(sentence))

        X = np.array([X_type_token, X_count_nouns]).T

        print X
        print X.shape

        if not hasattr(self, 'scalar'):
            self.scalar = StandardScaler().fit(X)
        return self.scalar.transform(X)
```

This feature transformer then needs to either take tagged text for the count_nouns() function or the raw text for type_token_ratio()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you have to do a **FeatureUnion** on 2 Transformers (TfidfTransformer and *POSTransformer*). Of course you need to define that POSTransformer.
Maybe this [article](http://zacstewart.com/2014/08/05/pipelines-of-featureunions-of-pipelines.html) will help you.

Maybe your pipeline will look like this.

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
  ('features', FeatureUnion([
    ('ngram_tf_idf', Pipeline([
      ('counts_ngram', CountVectorizer()),
      ('tf_idf_ngram', TfidfTransformer())
    ])),
    ('pos_tf_idf', Pipeline([
      ('pos', POSTransformer()),          
      ('counts_pos', CountVectorizer()),
      ('tf_idf_pos', TfidfTransformer())
    ])),
    ('measure_features', MeasureFeatures())
  ])),
  ('classifier', LinearSVC())
])
```

And this assume that **MeasureFeatures** and  **POSTransformer** are Transformers conform to the sklearn API.

Comment: I have added MeasureFeatures() in my latest edit. Basically it needs to take raw text for one set of features and pos tag set for the other set of features. Would having two MeasureFeature classes help? One for raw text features and one for pos tag features?

Comment: I don't really see your workflow here. Look at the one I proposed to you, the link and this example (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html). After that you just need to think about your workflow, what happens to your data.